# Using Input box for all variables in countif vba

Tags: excel, vba, countif, inputbox

I have tried to code a macro where a search is conducted for a specific text.
A)The column to search in, 
B)The column where the result should appear and
C) The text for which the search is being conducted
All are referred by respective input boxes.
The input box for columns to be searched and where output is to be placed **should only need the column name,(and not range)** indicated by letters (text and so string) as value.
For example, if a search in column Y is to be done the input box should only need entry of letter "Y". 
I have tried various permutations, but could not replace **Y2:Y&LastRow** in the code below, so that it **refers to the input from input box for the column to search in.**

The code is as follows:-

```
Sub CountIfAllVariablesFromInputBox()
    Dim LastRow    As Long
    Dim ChkColumn  As String
    'display an input box asking for column
    ChkColumn = InputBox( _
    "Please enter column to check")
    'if no input stop
    ColumnNumber = Columns(ChkColumn).Column
    If Len(ChkColumn) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No column entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim InputColumn    As String
    'display an input box asking for column
    InputColumn = InputBox( _
    "Please enter column to insert results")
    'if no input stop
    If Len(InputColumn) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No column entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If
'inputbox for text string to search for    
    Dim SuccessKeyWord As String
    SuccessKeyWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter KeyWord For Success", _
    Title:="KeyWord For Success", Default:="WOW!!")

    LastRow = Range(ChkColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(InputColumn & "1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Range("Y2:Y"&LastRow),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"
 End With
End Sub
```

Googling threw up so many ways to refer to ranges (with cells, cell, variables) that I am overwhelmed, unfortunately I could not get result by any of those.

I would be really thankful of your kind help.

I have posted a screenShot.sometimes I may need to search in column "W" and at others in column "Y". I need that flexibility by using the inputbox.

[Screen Shot of the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkkZa.png)

[Error after replacing the last line of the code by:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPyx.png)

```
Range(InputColumn & "1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Range(""" & ChkColumn & 2 & ":" & ChkColumn & """&LastRow),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"
```

or

```
Range(InputColumn & "1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Range(""" & ChkColumn & 2 & ":" & ChkColumn &LastRow & """),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"
```

Note:-

Search in column W

Result in column AA

Text to search WOW!!

Comment: Sidenote: better to use Application.Inputbox and use the Type parameter to return actual Range objects. You are currently at risk of other invalid inputs.

Comment: Furthermore, you are intertwining VBA syntax with worksheet syntax. Don't use Range within your formula text. Tip: Use debug.print before that line to see what it would return currently.

Comment: Try `"=COUNTIF(Y2:Y" & LastRow & "),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"`

Comment: @chrisneilsen sir i need to replace  that part altogether and use input box result in its place, that is, ChkColumn  in my code (the column where the search is to be conducted

Comment: what do you mean with could not replace Y2:Y&LastRow?

Comment: @user11982798 sir i need to replace that part altogether and use input box result in its place, that is, ChkColumn in my code (the column where the search is to be conducted

Comment: Please give example your input box and what will Y2:Y&LastRow be?

Comment: if chkColumn = C2 and inputcolumn D2, so D2="=COUNTIF(C2:C" & LastRow & "),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"?

Comment: @user11982798 I have posted a sceenShot.sometimes I may need to search in column "W" and at others in column "Y". I need that flexibility by using the inputbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed you want the user to select the columns

```
Sub CountIfAllVariablesFromInputBox()
    Dim LastRow As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim ChkColumn As Range
    Dim InputColumn As Range
    Dim SuccessKeyWord As String


    'display an input box asking for column
    Set ChkColumn = Application.InputBox("Please enter column to check", Type:=8)
    'if no input stop
    If Len(ChkColumn) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No column entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ColumnNumber = ChkColumn.Column

    'display an input box asking for column
    Set InputColumn = Application.InputBox( _
                      "Please enter column to insert results", Type:=8)
    'if no input stop
    If InputColumn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'inputbox for text string to search for
    SuccessKeyWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter KeyWord For Success", _
                              Title:="KeyWord For Success", Default:="WOW!!")

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, ColumnNumber), Cells(LastRow, ColumnNumber))
    Cells(1, InputColumn.Column) = "=COUNTIF(" & Rng.Address & ",""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"

End Sub
```

Comment: It really works!! I suppose I need to modify the Len part as now the input is range.Moreover is there a way to input just column number (like "W"), without having to select the range (or something like "W:W")? I am really very much thankful.

Comment: Using a code to enter a formula is not very practical. Why would you want something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Some modification from your line code:

```
Sub CountIfAllVariablesFromInputBox()
    Dim LastRow    As Long
    Dim ChkColumn  As String
    'display an input box asking for column
    ChkColumn = InputBox( _
    "Please enter column to check")
    'if no input stop
    On Error Resume Next
    ColumnNumber = Columns(ChkColumn).Column
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox "No column entered or Something Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim InputColumn  As String
    'display an input box asking for column
    On Error Resume Next
    InputColumn = InputBox( _
    "Please enter column to insert results")
    'if no input stop
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox "No column entered or Something Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


'inputbox for text string to search for
    Dim SuccessKeyWord As String
    SuccessKeyWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter KeyWord For Success", _
    Title:="KeyWord For Success", Default:="WOW!!")

    LastRow = Range(ChkColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(InputColumn & "1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Range(""" & ChkColumn & 2 & ":" & ChkColumn &LastRow & """),""" & SuccessKeyWord & """)"
 'End With
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, the code should be on these lines, but the code is resulting in error as shown in the screen shot above. Heartfelt thanks for the help.

Comment: Would you like to inform the formula after running procedure?

Comment: If formula is present, it would be useful for future reference, but is not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Finally got it working

```
Sub CountIfAllVariablesFromInputBox()
        Dim LastRow    As Long
        Dim ChkColumn  As String
        Dim InputColumn  As String
        Dim SuccessKeyWord As String
        Dim rng As Range
        'display an input box asking for column
        ChkColumn = Application.InputBox("Please enter column to check")
        'if no input stop
        On Error Resume Next
        ColumnNumber = Columns(ChkColumn).Column
        If Err.Description <> "" Then
            MsgBox "No column entered or Something Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        'display an input box asking for column
        On Error Resume Next
        InputColumn = Application.InputBox( _
        "Please enter column to insert results")
        'if no input stop
        If Err.Description <> "" Then
            MsgBox "No column entered or Something Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    'inputbox for text string to search for
        SuccessKeyWord = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter KeyWord For Success", _
        title:="KeyWord For Success", Default:="WOW!!")
        LastRow = Range(ChkColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Set rng = Range(ChkColumn & 2 & ":" & ChkColumn & LastRow)
        Range(InputColumn & "1").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, SuccessKeyWord)
    End Sub
```

Thanks @JvdV @chrisneilsen @user11982798 @Davesexcel